# After a while, my react application which is bundled into .exe file is not updating with values for every second which is coming from backend

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, websocket, signalr

**Some times Data is not updating in .exe file when every second there is a data which is pumping from backend to frontend.**

For my problem, currently i am using **React v16, .NET c#, SignalR, Websocket**. And i have bundled whole application into .exe application.
usually for every second, i am able to see the data which is coming from backend through websocket. after some time still websocket connect is in open state but data is not updating in my frontend and websocket is not receiving any new data. I have ensured that backend is still sending the data to front end. This is only happening in .exe file. Not in localhost instance (in localhost, application is working as expected).

I am not really sure what could be the cause for it.

This application has to run more than 24hrs as per the requirement. But as i mentioned above, in middle it is breaking.
To ensure is there any render issue from react component, I have added one counter component to the frontend which is pointing to redux store. Once application is crashed with no data, Still we are able to see the counter value which is updating for every second.

It would be really great for us to get your insights.